# Как сделать actionButton для уведомления которая будет удалять уведомления?

Tags: android, android-notification

Всем привет, я делаю приложение заметки, где по назначенному времени приходит уведомление,в уведомлении есть кнопка завершить которая должна закрывать уведомление, уведомления создаются в AlarmReceiver который у меня всегда в фоновом режиме, мне надо чтобы новое уведомление не удаляло старое для этого я сделал notification_id = System.currentTimeMillis()
И получается что для каждого уведомление есть свой уникальный айди, но появилась другая проблема, если я создам например первое уведомление с notification_id = 1, и второе уведомление с notification_id = 2

И получается так что при нажатии на кнопку завершить в первом уведомлении у которого notification_id был равен 1 не удалится так как моя переменная notification_id уже равна 2 а не 1 и следовательно удалится 2 уведомление а не первое! Как можно сделать так чтобы у меня удалялось уведомление то на котором будет нажата кнопка завершить чтобы а не так как у меня на данный момент